# SSRS Service unavailable HTTP 503

Tags: reporting-services

This Wednesday our report server stopped working.
When I open the URL http://ourdomain/ReportServer as set in `Report Server Configuration Manager`,

it writes `HTTP Error 503. The service is unavailable.`

I already tried to restart the service `SQL Server Reporting Services`.

I also tried in `Report Server Configuration Manager` under `Web Service URL` tab to rename the Virtual Directory to ReportServer2 than apply. The new URL wasn't working as well.

I noticed in one log from 12. 2. 2020
`library!WindowsService_31!a94!02/12/2020-02:12:42:: e ERROR: Throwing Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.EvaluationCopyExpiredException: , Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.EvaluationCopyExpiredException: The evaluation period for this instance of Microsoft SQL Server Reporting Services has expired.  A license is now required.;
servicecontroller!WindowsService_31!a94!02/12/2020-02:12:42:: e ERROR: StartService: Error Starting Service: Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.EvaluationCopyExpiredException: The evaluation period for this instance of Microsoft SQL Server Reporting Services has expired.  A license is now required.
appdomainmanager!DefaultDomain!a94!02/12/2020-02:12:42:: e ERROR: Exiting process because windows service failed to start.`

Comment: is there anything in any of the [SSRS log destinations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-server/reporting-services-log-files-and-sources?view=sql-server-ver15)?

Comment: Could you check the ReportServer database connection in the Report Server Configuration Manager?  At the same time, SSRS log files will give some detail about the issue.

Comment: @timur In the location `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server Reporting Services\SSRS\LogFiles` there are many log files. Even from the date 12. 2. 2020. I don't know what to look for in these files. It's much information.

Comment: @esat Yes, "test connection succeeded". Btw. the report server configuration manager is quite slow when changing something.

Comment: @timur Please, see the edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regardless of whether this is a root cause or not - I think you will be better off crossing this licesing error off your list to continue troubleshooting (I do however suspect this is it).

In short:

1. **Before doing anything, make sure you back up `ReportServer` DB!**
2. Try reinstalling SSRS edition to match your SQL Server and enter **the same** licence key ([find your SQL key](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/install-windows/find-reporting-services-product-key-ssrs?view=sql-server-2017) and check the key on SSRS installation media `\..\x64\DefaultSetup.ini` before running it)

There's a few forums around discussing the issue and highlighting different issues users had while trying to reinstall SSRS (I'll just link a few most relevant in my opinion - none of them are mine).

1. A [thread on social.microsoft.com](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/9212cce9-3ff1-445e-9e69-5b714619f4d0/ssrs-2017-is-stuck-in-evaluation-mode-and-has-stopped-working-even-though-we-upgraded-sql-to-a?forum=sqlreportingservices)
2. One seemingly successful experience from [community.spiceworks.com](https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/2165493-ssrs-license-listed-as-eval-and-it-shouldn-t-be)
3. And another one [from the same site](https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/2163721-ssrs-license-confusion?from_forum=36)

Hopefully that resolves your issue